# Let $\left\{y_{k} \right\}$ be any bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\left\{y_{k} \right\}$ be any bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

For each $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$ let $x_{k}=inf\left\{y_{j}:j\geq k \right\}$ and $z_{k}=sup\left\{y_{j}:j\geq  k \right\}$.

Prove that If $\left\{y_{k} \right\}$ converges, then $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }x_{k}=\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }z_{k}$ in which case $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }y_{k}$ is equal to this common limit.

Here's what I proved :

- $x_{k}\leq y_{k} \leq z_{k}$ for all $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$.
- $\left\{x_{k} \right\}$ is monotone increasing and bounded above and $\left\{z_{k} \right\}$ is monotone decreasing and bounded below.

My proof is :

Suppose $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }y_{k}=L$

For all $k\geq k_{0}, L-\varepsilon <y_{k}<L+\varepsilon$

(blank)

For all $k\geq k_{0}$, $L-\varepsilon <x_{k}\leq L$ and $L \leq z_{k}<L+\varepsilon$

$\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }x_{k}=\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }z_{k}=L$

How should I take the value of $\varepsilon$?

Comment: $x_k$ increasing and $\lim x_k=L$ implies that $x_k \leq L$ for all $k$. Similarly, $L \leq z_k$ for all $k$.

Comment: I prove that fact. How should I prove for all $k\geq k_{0}$, $L-\varepsilon <x_{k}$ and $z_{k}<L+\varepsilon$?

Comment: $\lim z_k = L$ and $z_k$ is decreasing, so there exists large $k_1$ such that $k \geq k_1$ implies $|z_k - L| = z_k - L < \epsilon$, i.e., $z_k < L + \epsilon$. Do similar thing to $x_k$ and get another $k_2$ s.t. $k \geq k_2$ implies $L-\epsilon < x_k$. Take $k_0 := \max\{k_1, k_2\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_{k}=inf\left\{y_{j}:j\geq k \right\}$

1. $(x_k) $ is an increasing sequence and bounded above.
2. $\alpha=\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k=\lim inf\left\{y_{j}:j\geq k \right\}$
3. There exists a subsequence of $(y_k) $ that converges to $\alpha$.

$z_{k}=sup\left\{y_{j}:j\geq  k \right\}$

1. $(z_k) $ is a decreasing sequence and bounded below.
2. $\beta=\lim_{k\to \infty} z_k=\lim sup\left\{y_{j}:j\geq k \right\}$
3. There exists a subsequence of $(y_k) $ that converges to $\beta$

$(y_k) $ convergent $\implies$  all subsequences converges to the same limit.

Hence, $\alpha=\lim y_k =\beta$